# How to access network service running on Android device from internet

Tags: android, networking, android-networking

I am running simple http service on port 8000 on my Android device. How can I access this from Another device over mobile data.

Thanks

Comment: For accessing another device's localhost, both the devices should be connected under the same local network (LAN). All other ways would be a workaround.

Comment: Over Wifi it's simple, but over cellular/mobile data it's probably not possible. Due to the sheer number of subscribers a mobile network may have it's very likely that the IP address of your phone is NAT'd several layers deep.

Answer (score 0):

Turning this into a proper answer since my comment was well-received.

Over WiFi, the process is simple. You find out the IP address of your device on your local network, and access it via another computer on the same network e.g. if your Android device has an IP address of `192.168.1.20`, you can access it from another machine at:

```
http://192.168.1.20:8000
```

Over mobile data, however, it's probably not possible. Consider that any single mobile network provider may have millions of subscribers but only a handful of public-facing IP addresses, these IP addresses cannot be assigned on a 1:1 basis. So instead these endpoints are split down into further subsets using [Network Address Translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), potentially several layers deep. From Wikipedia:

> Network address translation (NAT) is a method of remapping one IP address space into another by modifying network address information in the IP header of packets while they are in transit across a traffic routing device. The technique was originally used as a shortcut to avoid the need to readdress every host when a network was moved. It has become a popular and essential tool in conserving global address space in the face of IPv4 address exhaustion. One Internet-routable IP address of a NAT gateway can be used for an entire private network.

This ensures that a mobile network can continue to add subscribers and provide data services, but also means that initiating a direct connection to an individual device from **outside** the mobile network is near-enough impossible as you'd need to know the complete route to the device through private networks.

Comment: Thanks for explaining in detail. If however I buy a static IP address from my provider is it possible to route it to my mobile device somehow?

Comment: Again, very unlikely, given the sheer size and scale of mobile network providers, and the logistics of following you along cell towers (compared to, say, your friendly local professional ISP who can set up your fixed line to always be allocated a certain public-facing IP). You can ask, but I don't think you'd get very far, especially with the "big" providers who own and run the infrastructure.